# Download .csv with javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

i want generate .csv in javascript. i have the object, the name is "archivo". the 
This problem is when generate the file csv, in each line add ',', i don't know what happen

```
archivo=[], each line is string + '\n'. 
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {                
        var popup = window.open('','csv','');     
            popup.document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + archivo[i] + '</pre>';                  
    }else{       
        location.href='data:application/download; charset=utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(archivo);        
    }
```

any can help me?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think you have to put a semi-colon after `charset=utf-8`, not a comma.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a CSV generator library, that handles all this for you.

I've written a light-weight client-side CSV generator library that might come in handy. Check it out on http://atornblad.se/github/ *(scroll down to the headline saying **Client-side CSV file generator**)*

It requires a functioning `FileSaver` implementation handling calls to `window.saveAs()`. Check out Eli Grey's solution on http://eligrey.com/blog/post/saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side

When in place, you simply generate and save CSV files on the fly like this:

```
var propertyOrder = ["name", "age", "height"];

var csv = new Csv(propertyOrder);

csv.add({ name : "Anders",
          age : 38,
          height : "178cm" });

csv.add({ name : "John Doe",
          age : 50,
          height : "184cm" });

csv.saveAs("people.csv");
```